# Finding a binary matrix such that the given hamming weight is constant

Tags: matlab, hamming-distance

Given a square binary matrix. I want to get all possible binary matrices which are at `d` Hamming distance apart.

Suppose

```
A=[1 0 1; 
   0 1 1; 
   1 1 0].
```

Then a matrix which is one (d) Hamming distance apart is

```
[0 0 1; 
 0 1 1; 
 1 1 0].
```

Any help in Matlab base coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hoping that I got the definition of [`hamming weight`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) right in the given context. Based on that hope/assumption, this might be what you were after -

```
combs = dec2base(0:2^9-1,2,9)-'0'; %//'# Find all combinations
combs_3d = reshape(combs',3,3,[]); %//'# Reshape into a 3D array

%// Calculate the hamming weights between A and all combinations.
%// Choose the ones with hamming weights equal to `1`
out = combs_3d(:,:,sum(sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,A,combs_3d)),2),1)==1)
```

Thus, each 3D slice of `out` would give you such a `3 x 3` matrix with `1` hamming weight between them and `A`.

It looks like you have `9` such matrices -

```
out(:,:,1) =
     0     0     1
     0     1     1
     1     1     0
out(:,:,2) =
     1     0     1
     0     1     1
     0     1     0
out(:,:,3) =
     1     0     1
     0     0     1
     1     1     0
out(:,:,4) =
     1     0     1
     0     1     1
     1     0     0
out(:,:,5) =
     1     0     0
     0     1     1
     1     1     0
out(:,:,6) =
     1     0     1
     0     1     0
     1     1     0
out(:,:,7) =
     1     0     1
     0     1     1
     1     1     1
out(:,:,8) =
     1     1     1
     0     1     1
     1     1     0
out(:,:,9) =
     1     0     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     0
```

---

### Edit

For big `n`, you need to use loops it seems -

```
n = size(A,1);
nsq = n^2;

A_col = A(:).';
out = zeros(n,n,nsq);
count = 1;
for k1 = 0:2^nsq-1
    match1 = dec2bin(k1,nsq)-'0';
    if sum(abs(match1-A_col))==1
        out(:,:,count) = reshape(match1,n,n);
        count = count + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: `Humming weight`, sounds comedy, made me laugh :D

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar haha sorry got carried away with the typo in the question that I didn't realise! :) Thanks for pointing out that one!

Comment: @Divakar, if the size of the matrix is higher then 3. Suppose 8. Then how do handle the case? This code wont work due to maximum variable size.

Comment: @SkSarifHassan Check out the Edit section?

Comment: @SkSarifHassan BTW, `match1 = bitget(k1,nsq:-1:1)` could be faster.